# Modify field in node drupal 7

Tags: entities, nodes, hooks

I have field "myfield" in a node. The field is created in the content, not by hook. I want to change the value of that field. I do not want to display the value from database, but my value let's say random number. I tried to do this with hook_node_view and with hook_entity_view but I cannot change it on the display. Here is my code:

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode) {
  if ($node->type == 'my_node_type') {
    if ($node->nid == 46) {
      $node->myfield['und'][0]['value'] = 55;
//or I tried with $node->content and no success
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing? Can you help me, please!
Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this line instead:

```
$node->content['myfield'][0]['#markup'] = '55';
```

Comment: Hi, I just tested and it is not working, too. The value with dump is changes but not on the display. Maybe I missed something but I do not know what. Thanks.

Comment: OK. It is working. I was testing the field that is editable (from editable fields module) but still I need also to change editable fields values.